# Reduce video buffering

Tags: android, video-streaming, media-player, rtsp, buffering

I'm playing video on Android using media player via RTSP.  The player takes about 12s to buffer before it starts playing.  Anyone know how I can convince the player to buffer less?  I have full control over the RTSP server and the SDP it returns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per usual, as soon as I decide I should ask a question I work out the answer.  I have a line "b=AS:91" in my SDP.  If I reduce the number the amount of buffering decreases - so b=AS:2 gives about 4 or 5s buffering.

Comment: Thanks for updating, this is useful.

Comment: It was a joke, I am not in favor of promoting such a bad practice... Just wanted to have some fun, nothing more. That's why I have put #PracticalJoke at the end.... sorry if anybody misunderstood this comment

Comment: I'm trying to send a VLC generated stream to an android phone. How did you generate the stream and the sdp description?