# Android SDK : Samba server streaming video to Android using VideoView?

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, httpserver, jcifs

I need play video from samba to android device streaming. I've been look for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17442941/how-to-stream-video-across-lan-in-android-videoview) and someone say that :

1. Using JCIFS to scan for and "see" the share: http://jcifs.samba.org/
2. Implementing a simple HTTP server (NanoHttpd) to stream the content
   via http: https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd
3. Passing the `http://localhost/myvideo` link to the VideoView

I'm already use JCIFS to get SmbFile in my project and I also get inputstream( smbfile.getInputStream() ).
Now I import NanoHttpd and I create simple HTTP server that http address is`http://localhost:8080`

```
private class MyHTTPD extends NanoHTTPD {
    public MyHTTPD() throws IOException {
        super(8080);
    }

    @Override
    public Response serve(String uri, String method, Properties header, Properties parms, Properties files) {
        InputStream is = new SmbFile(filePath,auth).getInputStream();

                  //return index as response
        return new NanoHTTPD.Response(HTTP_OK, "video/mp4", is);
    }
}

server = new MyHTTPD();
server.start();
```

But my http address is different from `http://localhost/myvideo`, I don't know how to get right http address and put it in to VideoView.
I don't know how to get path like `http://localhost/myvideo` .
Thanks for help....

The other question : Can I use VideoView playing video from InputStream ?

Comment: Hi - I'm not sure what the problem is? Is your server working fine? When it's running can you go to a browser on your device and access http://localhost:8080 and you get a video?

Comment: If I use FileInputStream from local file then I can get a video, but it didn't work from smbfileinputstream... I think that it's different between fileinputstream and smbfileinputstream. this is the other question i asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945482/whats-different-between-sambafileinputstream-and-fileinputstream

Comment: Finally, I find a sample code for Android samba stream...
[android-smb-streamer](https://code.google.com/p/android-smb-streaming/)

Comment: @henry4343 can you please share you code you have implemented to play video with samba sharing.. I am searching for it very long please tell if you can help me