# how to open a audio and video embed in url on android browser

Tags: android, url, android-webview, android-mediaplayer, android-browser

In my project i need to open the url that contain embed audio and video in the same link i try lot of method to open but i cant able to get the output and lot of link for this till it is not clear for this type of problem. I'm using 2.3 version devices

I have used the intent method

```
  Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
            Uri.parse("http://survey.euro.confirmit.com/extwix/test_p1837764731.aspx?__etk=GMYRUFKMQZTQ&ftouch=1679&pin=346"));
            startActivity(newIntent);
```

and i have used the WebView method also till now i cant get it working

```
web = (WebView) surveyView.findViewById(R.id.webView_survey);
settings = web.getSettings();
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
// settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
// settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
web.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
web.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    if (!v.hasFocus()) {
          v.requestFocus();
    }
    break;
    }
    return false;
    }
    });
web.loadUrl("http://survey.euro.confirmit.com/extwix/test_p1837764731.aspx?__etk=GMYRUFKMQZTQ&ftouch=1679&pin=346");
}
```

can any one help me so solve this problem

Comment: can you provide the demo link . Maybe  I can help you

Comment: that is the i'm using check the link im using in the coding

Comment: I opened the link but there is nothing any audio/ vedio there

Comment: just click the forward button and go to next next screen u will find the audio and video in it

Comment: okay ... on which version you are testing and when you used webview what error you getting or what problem you faced?

Comment: actually im not getting any error only thing is it is not playing any audio or video i'm using 2.2 and 4.3 os

Comment: have you checked logcat .... may be you are getting something

Comment: nothing is coming in the logcat no error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54038/discussion-between-a-m-and-jagan).

Comment: Well I think, passing the URL directly to the web view will never help. Instead, reading the stream returned by the server and parsing it for audio and video, should be the way to go about it.

Comment: @Eu.Dr. but the audio and video is embed to the url link how do u stream that all i need is to user the url same function as desktop in android

Answer (score 1):

Extract the URL using a suitable [HTML Parser](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers), then you can supply the URL to the MediaPlayer object to play your resource.

For Audio you can refer to the Android docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html). The MediaPlayer class has a setDataSource() method that lets you specify an external URI to be played.

For Video, the VideoView class has a setVideoURI() method that can accomplish the same. Maybe going a bit deeper into the docs will yield more answers. :)

Comment: but this is embed audio and video URL u can not simple used this url as audio or video in this url there are some content that also must be display

Comment: i need a solution coding for this question can u provide it

Comment: I am not understanding your question. Do you want to get audio/video embedded in another site? Or audio/video provided as URLs?

Comment: open the url in desktop and c the flow that some flow must come in android device if i used the same url that the question

Comment: http://survey.euro.confirmit.com/extwix/test_p1719865390.aspx?__etk=JFZWRJKESUUD&ftouch=2299&pin=156 and just click the forword button and u will find the audio and video in the url

Comment: Ah, the mp3 url is embedded in the page. You could use an HTML(XML) parser to extract the url and then play it. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: can u please give me some example for this type of thing bcz i'm new to this

Comment: i cant get you what i'll used in this url u sent

Comment: You can use the HTML parsers in that link to extract the URLs for audio and video.

Comment: how do i used the HTML parser in this url

Comment: RTFM! If you really can't figure this out, I doubt you'll be able to complete your project, mate.

Comment: dude can u give me some example for HTML parser so that i can used it in the app

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is with you Url of video.

When you would like to stream the video your url should be explicit like ,

```
String vidAddress = "https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4";
```

Please go though [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5339647/501483)

Comment: but the url work when v used in the desktop same thing i need to show in the android

Comment: that why i mention it is embed audio and video to open in browser

Comment: you must had open that url in some of the desktop browser then , internet browser manage this thing itself since its one kind of software .  and what do you mean by embedded video ? are you targeting HLS streaming ?

Comment: if u c the inspect element u'll find this coding <embed src="https://icontrol.ipinionsurveys.com/Uploads//MediaFiles/6697/MediaFile24Jan2014044217.mp3" width="480" height="370" type="audio/mp3" autoplay="true">

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as reference [how to do video streaming in android](https://foxdogstudios.com/peepers.html) it helped me with the approach.