# Android VideoView RTSP delay

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp, android-videoview, rtmp

I am opening a RTSP stream of an IP camera in my Android application through VideoView. There is a problem that It has a great delay that reaches more than 20 seconds! although viewing the Camera from an ordinary PC via its browser there is no such delay. Any Ideas please?

My Code:

```
        String path="rtsp://192.168.1.20/3gpp";
        myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
        myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        myVideoView.requestFocus();
        myVideoView.start();
```

Comment: This post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937241/reduce-video-buffering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MJPEG stream, instead of RTSP. After lots of research, I´ve found an MJPEG viewer class that plays live stream near in real time (depending on your network connection).

Here´s the code [Android and MJPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205191/android-and-mjpeg)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following for this

MjpegSample Class

```
package de.mjpegsample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import de.mjpegsample.MjpegView.MjpegInputStream;
import de.mjpegsample.MjpegView.MjpegView;

public class MjpegSample extends Activity {

private MjpegView mv;
private static final int MENU_QUIT = 1;

/* Creates the menu items */
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {    
menu.add(0, MENU_QUIT, 0, "Quit");
return true;
}

/* Handles item selections */
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {    
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_QUIT:
            finish();
            return true;    
        }    
    return false;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    //sample public cam
    String URL = "http://gamic.dnsalias.net:7001/img/video.mjpeg";

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    mv = new MjpegView(this);
    setContentView(mv);        
    mv.setSource(MjpegInputStream.read(URL));
    mv.setDisplayMode(MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT);
    mv.showFps(false);
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mv.stopPlayback();
}
}
```

MjepgView

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MjpegView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
public final static int POSITION_UPPER_LEFT  = 9;
public final static int POSITION_UPPER_RIGHT = 3;
public final static int POSITION_LOWER_LEFT  = 12;
public final static int POSITION_LOWER_RIGHT = 6;

public final static int SIZE_STANDARD   = 1; 
public final static int SIZE_BEST_FIT   = 4;
public final static int SIZE_FULLSCREEN = 8;

private MjpegViewThread thread;
private MjpegInputStream mIn = null;    
private boolean showFps = false;
private boolean mRun = false;
private boolean surfaceDone = false;    
private Paint overlayPaint;
private int overlayTextColor;
private int overlayBackgroundColor;
private int ovlPos;
private int dispWidth;
private int dispHeight;
private int displayMode;

public class MjpegViewThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private int frameCounter = 0;
    private long start;
    private Bitmap ovl;

    public MjpegViewThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context) { mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder; }

    private Rect destRect(int bmw, int bmh) {
        int tempx;
        int tempy;
        if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_STANDARD) {
            tempx = (dispWidth / 2) - (bmw / 2);
            tempy = (dispHeight / 2) - (bmh / 2);
            return new Rect(tempx, tempy, bmw + tempx, bmh + tempy);
        }
        if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_BEST_FIT) {
            float bmasp = (float) bmw / (float) bmh;
            bmw = dispWidth;
            bmh = (int) (dispWidth / bmasp);
            if (bmh > dispHeight) {
                bmh = dispHeight;
                bmw = (int) (dispHeight * bmasp);
            }
            tempx = (dispWidth / 2) - (bmw / 2);
            tempy = (dispHeight / 2) - (bmh / 2);
            return new Rect(tempx, tempy, bmw + tempx, bmh + tempy);
        }
        if (displayMode == MjpegView.SIZE_FULLSCREEN) return new Rect(0, 0, dispWidth, dispHeight);
        return null;
    }

    public void setSurfaceSize(int width, int height) {
        synchronized(mSurfaceHolder) {
            dispWidth = width;
            dispHeight = height;
        }
    }

    private Bitmap makeFpsOverlay(Paint p, String text) {
        Rect b = new Rect();
        p.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), b);
        int bwidth  = b.width()+2;
        int bheight = b.height()+2;
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bwidth, bheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
        p.setColor(overlayBackgroundColor);
        c.drawRect(0, 0, bwidth, bheight, p);
        p.setColor(overlayTextColor);
        c.drawText(text, -b.left+1, (bheight/2)-((p.ascent()+p.descent())/2)+1, p);
        return bm;           
    }

    public void run() {
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        PorterDuffXfermode mode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER);
        Bitmap bm;
        int width;
        int height;
        Rect destRect;
        Canvas c = null;
        Paint p = new Paint();
        String fps = "";
        while (mRun) {
            if(surfaceDone) {
                try {
                    c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                    synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                        try {
                            bm = mIn.readMjpegFrame();
                            destRect = destRect(bm.getWidth(),bm.getHeight());
                            c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                            c.drawBitmap(bm, null, destRect, p);
                            if(showFps) {
                                p.setXfermode(mode);
                                if(ovl != null) {
                                    height = ((ovlPos & 1) == 1) ? destRect.top : destRect.bottom-ovl.getHeight();
                                    width  = ((ovlPos & 8) == 8) ? destRect.left : destRect.right -ovl.getWidth();
                                    c.drawBitmap(ovl, width, height, null);
                                }
                                p.setXfermode(null);
                                frameCounter++;
                                if((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) >= 1000) {
                                    fps = String.valueOf(frameCounter)+"fps";
                                    frameCounter = 0; 
                                    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                    ovl = makeFpsOverlay(overlayPaint, fps);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {}
                    }
                } finally { if (c != null) mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c); }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void init(Context context) {
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    thread = new MjpegViewThread(holder, context);
    setFocusable(true);
    overlayPaint = new Paint();
    overlayPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    overlayPaint.setTextSize(12);
    overlayPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
    overlayTextColor = Color.WHITE;
    overlayBackgroundColor = Color.BLACK;
    ovlPos = MjpegView.POSITION_LOWER_RIGHT;
    displayMode = MjpegView.SIZE_STANDARD;
    dispWidth = getWidth();
    dispHeight = getHeight();
}

public void startPlayback() { 
    if(mIn != null) {
        mRun = true;
        thread.start();         
    }
}

public void stopPlayback() { 
    mRun = false;
    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry) {
        try {
            thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}

public MjpegView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { super(context, attrs); init(context); }
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int f, int w, int h) { thread.setSurfaceSize(w, h); }

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
    surfaceDone = false; 
    stopPlayback(); 
}

public MjpegView(Context context) { 
    super(context); 
    init(context); 
    }    
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
    surfaceDone = true; 
    }
public void showFps(boolean b) { 
    showFps = b; 
    }
public void setSource(MjpegInputStream source) { 
    mIn = source; 
    startPlayback();
    }
public void setOverlayPaint(Paint p) { 
    overlayPaint = p; 
    }
public void setOverlayTextColor(int c) { 
    overlayTextColor = c; 
    }
public void setOverlayBackgroundColor(int c) { 
    overlayBackgroundColor = c; 
    }
public void setOverlayPosition(int p) { 
    ovlPos = p; 
    }
public void setDisplayMode(int s) { 
    displayMode = s; 
    }
}
```

MjpegInputStream

```
package de.mjpegsample.MjpegView;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class MjpegInputStream extends DataInputStream {
private final byte[] SOI_MARKER = { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xD8 };
private final byte[] EOF_MARKER = { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xD9 };
private final String CONTENT_LENGTH = "Content-Length";
private final static int HEADER_MAX_LENGTH = 100;
private final static int FRAME_MAX_LENGTH = 40000 + HEADER_MAX_LENGTH;
private int mContentLength = -1;

public static MjpegInputStream read(String url) {
    HttpResponse res;
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();     
    try {
        res = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(URI.create(url)));
        return new MjpegInputStream(res.getEntity().getContent());              
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    return null;
}

public MjpegInputStream(InputStream in) { super(new BufferedInputStream(in, FRAME_MAX_LENGTH)); }

private int getEndOfSeqeunce(DataInputStream in, byte[] sequence) throws IOException {
    int seqIndex = 0;
    byte c;
    for(int i=0; i < FRAME_MAX_LENGTH; i++) {
        c = (byte) in.readUnsignedByte();
        if(c == sequence[seqIndex]) {
            seqIndex++;
            if(seqIndex == sequence.length) return i + 1;
        } else seqIndex = 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

private int getStartOfSequence(DataInputStream in, byte[] sequence) throws IOException {
    int end = getEndOfSeqeunce(in, sequence);
    return (end < 0) ? (-1) : (end - sequence.length);
}

private int parseContentLength(byte[] headerBytes) throws IOException, NumberFormatException {
    ByteArrayInputStream headerIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(headerBytes);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(headerIn);
    return Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty(CONTENT_LENGTH));
}   

public Bitmap readMjpegFrame() throws IOException {
    mark(FRAME_MAX_LENGTH);
    int headerLen = getStartOfSequence(this, SOI_MARKER);
    reset();
    byte[] header = new byte[headerLen];
    readFully(header);
    try {
        mContentLength = parseContentLength(header);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { 
        mContentLength = getEndOfSeqeunce(this, EOF_MARKER); 
    }
    reset();
    byte[] frameData = new byte[mContentLength];
    skipBytes(headerLen);
    readFully(frameData);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(frameData));
}
}
```